# How do I write an Update SQL to copy multiple records from one table to update the corresponding field on another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to select all the records in one field that are grouped together by a foreign key, and update the corresponding field in another table that is grouped by a foreign key. The foreign keys between the two tables are different and are not related to each other.

Ideally, I'd like the tables to go from looking like State A to State B

**State A**

```
tbl_Unlisted                   tbl_Listed
ListID      ListDate           ListID      ListDate
  43       04/01/2018            64
  43       04/02/2018            64
  43       04/03/2018            64
  43       04/04/2018            64
```

**State B**

```
tbl_Unlisted                   tbl_Listed
ListID      ListDate           ListID      ListDate
  43       04/01/2018            64       04/01/2018
  43       04/02/2018            64       04/02/2018
  43       04/03/2018            64       04/03/2018
  43       04/04/2018            64       04/04/2018
```

Here is my stab at the Update SQL:

```
UPDATE tbl_Listed
SET ListDate = tbl_Unlisted.ListDate
FROM tbl_Unlisted
WHERE tbl_List.ListID = 64
AND tbl_Unlisted.ListID = 43;
```

tbl_Listed is the table that I want to update
tbl_Unlisted is the table that contains the existing records
ListDate is the field that I want to be copied from tbl_Unlisted and updated into tbl_Listed
ListID is the field that contains the foreign key for tbl_Listed and tbl_Unlisted

However, the Update SQL throws a syntax error when I try to execute it.

Any idea on what I should change? Thank you in advance!

> EDIT - Updated from comments

*I should clarify that there is another field on each table that will be unique to each record so that row #1 = A, row #2 = B, row #3 = C, row #4 = D*

Comment: How is it supposed to know which date to put in each row?  You'll need some way to determine that row #3 from your source table should map to row #3 in your destination table.

Comment: I should clarify that there is another field on each table that will be unique to each record so that row #1 = A, row #2 = B, row #3 = C, row #4 = D

Comment: What you want to do is immensely easier to accomplish through Access-VBA. If you know what you're doing with recordsets, you can just set them with those fields in mind as you run through the recordset. Otherwise, IIRC, the only way to accomplish this with SQL is to have an "in-between" table and then update from that.

Comment: I should also clarify that I am already doing this through Access-VBA. I've browsed through some similar threads that have leveraged recordsets, but I'm not too sure how to use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leverage SQL Query Design mode and create this query easily

If you;re going to use VBA - I'd suggest parameterized query for the different ListIDs

This will work if your FieldName for the matching rows is called "ROW"

```
UPDATE tbl_Listed 
INNER JOIN tbl_Unlisted 
ON tbl_Listed.Row = tbl_Unlisted.Row 
SET tbl_Listed.ListDate = [tbl_Listed].[ListDate]
WHERE (((tbl_Listed.ListDate) Is Null) 
AND ((tbl_Listed.ListID)=64) 
AND ((tbl_Unlisted.ListID)=43));
```

Comment: Thank you - this seems to work great. I had not thought of joining the two tables together based on the repetitive row!